# Quantifying change in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, quantifiers

I need to a way to express a change in the structure of a given graph `G`, such that the original graph is `G` and the changed graph is `G'`. A change in the graph can be the addition or removal of any number of vertices and/or edges.

Currently, my thought is to express the change as two percentages: the number of vertices in `G'` as a percentage of the number of vertices in `G`, and the same for edges. However, it occurs to me that removing a vertex also means removing all edges connected to it.

Are there any standard ways of quantifying the change in a graphs structure?

Comment: You may find some results searching phrases like "graph distance" or "graph metric".

Answer (score 2):

If you only allow addition or deletion of edges, then there is a way of measuring how "far apart" two graphs are.  If $G$ and $G'$ are two graphs on the same vertex set, the *edit distance* between $G$ and $G'$ is the smallest number of edges of $G$ that must be deleted and non-edges of $G$ that must be added in order to transform $G$ into $G'$.  In symbols,
$$d(G, G') = \lvert E(G) \triangle E(G') \rvert,$$
where $A \triangle B$ denotes the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$.

Edit distance was introduced by Axenovich, Kezdy, and Martin in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0606/0606475v1.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

[This paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CGUQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uvm.edu%2F~pdodds%2Ffiles%2Fpapers%2Fothers%2Fnetworks%2Fgraph_distance.ps&ei=sqzkUIWsMoeD0QHzvoFA&usg=AFQjCNFmu8XARIFaD3JWLGUGjRoiZ036og&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.dmQ) describes a metric based on maximal common subgraphs, which the authors claim is superior to the edit distance in some applications.

Comment: When I clicked on the link provided, I got a "document not found" message.

Comment: @AndrewUzzell I've provided an alternate link. Hopefully this one works as advertised.